# NodeJS can't returned data from imported module is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
    var results;
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM avg_table WHERE id = ?';

    connection.query(sql, [id], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        results = JSON.stringify(result);
    });
    return results;
};

module.exports = { listRecord};
```

Hello. When i try to read returned results data from another file it says undefined.
I import like this down below

`const dbHandler = require('./dbHandler');`

and im trying to use like this

```
    .route('/')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.send('Kayit Listele');
        console.log(dbHandler.listRecord(req.query.id));
    })
```

Couldn't find any way to fix this. Than you everyone for helping

Comment: @BGPHiJACK — What good will that do? When `connect.query` calls the callback, it doesn't pay any attention to the return value.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK its still undefined